# Drupal 7 - Search Results Pager

Tags: drupal, search, pager

I have tried everything I know how on Drupal to confirm my search results page to show the pager at the bottom.  I work at a library and know there are several pages that mention library but only ten will show up on the first page which is expected but there is no option to view anymore after the first page.  I've searched on Drupal and looked at the code and it appears to be the same, however, I'm unable to get the pager functionality to work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

if you are  trying to make query resut as a pager try to do as the following

```
$query = db_select('node', 'n')->extend('PagerDefault');
->condition('type', 'blog') // you query condition
->fields('n', array('title')) // the fields that you request from database
->limit(10); // the number of result/row per page
$queryresult = $query->execute() ; 

$content = '';
foreach ($queryresult as $row) {
  $content .= $row->title."<br/>"; // the row view content
}
$content .= theme('pager'); // this will display the pagination content
echo $content;
```